# How to do multiple class selectors in Stylus CSS pre-processor

Tags: css, stylus

How do you do/can you do this in Stylus

```
.classA.classB {
    color: red;
}
```

Note, I **do** mean ***.classA.classB*** not ***.classA .classB*** (they're different)

I thought this would do it

```
.classA
    .classB
        color red
```

But that does this (which makes sense I guess)

```
.classA .classB{color:#f00}
```

I realise I can do this

```
.classA.classB
    color red
```

But that doesn't feel very "Stylus" and would become clumsy as/if you nested further

Thanks
Jim

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should use [parent reference](http://learnboost.github.io/stylus/docs/selectors.html#parent-reference) there — use an ampersand symbol (`&`) to define where the parent selector would go:

```
.classA
    &.classB
        color red
```

this would render to

```
.classA.classB{color:#f00}
```

Answer (score -4):

The right way:

```
.class
  &A&
    &B
      color red
```